# how to get row values from a delta table in Azure Databricks cluster?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

i was able to get row values from delta table using foreachWriter in spark-shell and cmd but while writing the same code in azure databricks it doesn't work.

```scala
val process_deltatable=read_deltatable.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row]
  {
    def process(value: Row):Unit ={ 
      val Telemetery= value.getString(0)
      println(Telemetery)
    }
    def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true
    def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
  }
)

val xyz=process_deltatable.start()
```

Is there any way to get row by row values in azure databricks from a streaming delta table?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What error do you get?

Comment: Get Streaming data from delta table and apply drool rule on them. I don't get any error ...but it doesn't work either @Alex Ott

Answer (score 0):

We can get streaming data by saving it as table to specific location and load it.
Here is the altered code.

```
val  process_deltatable=read_deltatable.writeStream.foreach(new  ForeachWriter[Row]{
        def process(value: Row):Unit ={
        print(value)
        }
        def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true 
        
        def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}})
   val  xyz=process_deltatable.option("checkpointLocation","dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/desdelta/chkpoints").format("delta").start("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/desdelta/data")
```

Here while saving i specified checkpoint and data saving loaction.
After saving it you can retrieve it by running following code,

```
var  df = spark.read.format("delta").load("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/desdelta/data/")
display(df)
```

Here are the results

[image]

This are the row in source delta table.
Lets run the write stream code.
[image]
This is the result got by running writestream code.
Now i insert a single row to source table.

[image]
[image]
New row is added to source, Now lets check in destination.
[image]
Yes you can see the new row is added.
And you see in the databricks dashboard having spike when the new record is added.
[image]

If you need to see the full files and path you can run below code in the cell.

```
%fs
ls user/hive/warehouse/desdelta/data
```

[image]
Here you can see the files generated for any updation in source table.

Comment: what to do if i want to print the values of name column one by one @JayashankarGS?

Comment: You can use this code after loading data from destination path.
`var t = df.select("name").map(r => {("hi "+r.getString(0))})`, 
`t.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to apply transformation to each row, then you either need to use the `map` function on the DataFrame ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map%5BU%5D(func:org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction%5BT,U%5D,encoder:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D)), or define & use user-defined function (UDF). And then write to the Delta Lake table as normal write operation:

```scala
// Adjust record to your row structure
case class Record(timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp, value: Long)

val df = spark.readStream.format("rate").load()
val df2 = df.as[Record].map(x => {
  // do something with your record
  x
})
df2.writeStream.format("delta")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/stream1-cp")
  .start("/tmp/stream1")
```